# JsonConvert in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, json

I'm working in ASP.Net, JsonConvert doesn't work.How can I use JsonConvert?

I have already download NewtonSoft and write this string(using Newtonsoft;) to my project.

```
 public void FillDataGrid()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string json;
            string url = "http://192.168.0.111:2903/MigraPlus.asmx/GetDataJson";
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                json = client.DownloadString(url);
            }
            string[] json1 = json.Split('>');
            string[] json2 = json1[2].Split('<');
            json = json2[0];
            dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(DataTable));
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Could you please update the value of `json` variable?

Comment: I found solution.It is simple that:

Comment: dt = (DataTable)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(DataTable));

Comment: I wrote  [using Newtonsoft.Json;] instead of [using Newtonsoft;] and it works.